# Cant execute script in parent folder

Tags: python

I am trying to execute/call a python script that resides in another directory.

**My Problem:** When I attempt to open/call the file I get the error

> '..' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file

My python code to execute the python file is:

```
os.system("../test.py abc")
```

I have also tried this but I get the same error on a DIFFERENT part of the string:

```
os.system(os.getcwd()+"/../test.py abc")
# results in "c:/users/jim/work products/python/testdir/../test.py abc"
```

Error:

> 'c:/users/jim/work ' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file

Comment: Try this: os.system(r'../test.py abc')

Comment: Nope doesn't work, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows you should use '..\\executeablename' to run a program or script in the parent directory, not '../' the unix style.

And, to ensure the script can run property, a 'python' is better to be added before the command.

So I think this situation should be:

```
os.system("python ..\\test.py abc")
```

It has not been tested since I am using linux, you can just try.

BTW, 'os.system' is kinda deprecated and the subprocess module is recommend to use when execute system level command.

Answer (score 0):

A .py file isn't an executable, so that won't work on Windows. You have to run it with python.exe:

```
import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.call([sys.executable, '../test.py', 'abc'])
```

You could do this with system, but I figure this is easier because you don't have to quote the filename.

Comment: But os.system("test.py abc") works. As long as I have test.py in the same directory I can run the script in a console window and access the commandline argument 'abc'. It should work with a file in the parent directory shouldn't it?